# Mapping of a JSON object into another WSO2 ESB

Tags: json, object, wso2, datamapper, wso2-esb

I'm trying to map a result json object that I've gotten into another json object in wso2 through the data mapper in wso2 esb integrator.
Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

Input json file to map:

```
"Id": "degradation",
"Value": "4",
```

Output json file to get:

```
"result": {
  "degradation": 4
}
```

Any idea of how can I manage to do this in the integrator? And in case that its not possible, any alternative solution to consider (libraries, another easier framework maybe...) ?

Comment: "Any idea of how can I manage to do this in the integrator?" Can you explain this phrase? What do you mean by Integrator?

Comment: By integrator I meant the WSO2 ESB, sry for the confusion made

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Payload Factory mediator to achieve the above, if the structure of input and output payload is static.

Below is a sample API which you can test it out. Send a POST request to this API with your input payload and the output will be converted as you expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="testPayload" context="/testPayload">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{"result" : {"$1":"$2"}}</format>
                <args>
                   <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.Id"/>
                   <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.Value"/>
                </args>
             </payloadFactory>
             <respond/>>
        </inSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```